# Running a lottery within a pacman game

Tags: javascript, pacman

I want to find a pacman game written in javascript and find where it detects the winning. Then I can write my own code bellow it to run a simple lottery. I have checked out a few samples but couldn't find where it finds out the user has won. I need something like google;s one.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You clear a level in pacman when you eat all of the dots.

```
if(remainingDots == 0) {
    // you beat the level
}
```